# RSpec - Testing errors for 2 attributes that share the same validation(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have two attributes within my model that share the same validations

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, length: {minimum: 2}
```

Right now I have the `:first_name` attribute tested as follows:

```
RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  it 'is invalid if the first name is less than two characters'
    user = User.create(
      first_name: 'a'
    )
  expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name)
end
```

For the sake of a developer who isn't familiar with how I've setup my model I wanted to explicitly state the two attributes' relationship with something like this:

```
it 'is invalid if the first name and/or last name has less than two characters'
  user = User.create(
    first_name: 'a',
    last_name: 'b
  )
  expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name, :last_name)
```

Obviously this throws the error:

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

The same thing would apply if I had instituted 2 two validations:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, length: {minimum: 2}, format: {with: /^([^\d\W]|[-])*$/}
```

And try to test for 2 errors:

```
it 'is invalid if the first name and/or last name has less than two characters and has special characters'
  user = User.create(
    first_name: '@',
    last_name: '#
  )
  expect(user).to have(2).errors_on(:first_name, :last_name)
```

Comment: is the purpose of `length: {minimum: true}` to make sure it's not blank?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now changed to: `length: {minimum: 2}`. The purpose is to ensure they type more than 2 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RSpec 3.x, you can compound expectations with `.and`:

```
it 'is invalid if the first name and/or last name has less than two characters' do
  user = User.create(first_name: 'a', last_name: 'b')
  expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name).and have(1).errors_on(:last_name)
end
```

Check out the [rspec-expectations](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/compound-expectations) documentation for more info.

For RSpec 2.x, you'll need to do one of these:

```
it 'is invalid if the first name and/or last name has less than two characters' do
  user = User.create(first_name: 'a', last_name: 'b')
  expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name) && have(1).errors_on(:last_name)
end

# or
it 'is invalid if the first name and/or last name has less than two characters' do
  user = User.create(first_name: 'a', last_name: 'b')
  expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name)
  expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:last_name)
end
```

It's not as pretty, but it should work.

**EDIT:**

OP was using `rspec-collection_matchers` gem. That gem's custom matchers do not include RSpec 3 mixin module `RSpec::Matchers::Composable`, so the `#and` method goes unrecognized.

There are a few things to do to circumvent this issue. The easiest is to use the `&&` technique above (in my RSpec 2.x suggestions). To use **only** RSpec 3 matchers, you need to use `be_valid`:

```
it 'is invalid if the first name and/or last name has less than two characters' do
  user = User.create(first_name: 'a', last_name: 'b')
  expect(user).to_not be_valid
end
```

Of course, this does not distinguish between `first_name` errors and `last_name` errors as was originally intended. To do that with the `be_valid` matcher, you'd have to break the test into two tests:

```
it 'is invalid if the first name has less than two characters' do
  user = User.create(first_name: 'a', last_name: 'abc')
  expect(user).to_not be_valid
end

it 'is invalid if the last name has less than two characters' do
  user = User.create(first_name: 'abc', last_name: 'a')
  expect(user).to_not be_valid
end
```

Comment: I ran into this error `undefined method 'and' for #<User:0x007ff26a491420>`

Comment: I assumed you were working with RSpec 3.x. I've edited my answer to reflect your options in RSpec 2.x.

Comment: I assumed that as well until now. Originally I had my gemfile setup like this: `gem 'rspec-rails'`. But now after you mentioned it I changed it to:  `gem 'rspec-rails, '~> 3.0.0'` but still to no avail. Is there anything else I need to change anywhere else to indicate the version change? I assumed that not specifying the version number automatically gave me the latest one.

Comment: Run `bundle update rspec-rails` after you add that line to your Gemfile.

Comment: Even after upgrading I'm still having no luck. Can we meetup in a chat?

Comment: I'm on my phone ATM so I can't chat. Have you tried the `&&` method I listed for RSPEC 2.x?

Comment: Yeah. Both passed thanks. Let me know when you're free to chat. I'm stumped as to why I can't get the first test to work. I even started a new project just to see what the deal is but still no luck.

Comment: Sure thing. I should be free tomorrow. I'll try to look into it before then as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62828/discussion-between-johnson-and-carl-edwards).

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should look like this:

```
it 'invalid length' do
  user = User.new(first_name: '@', last_name: '#')
  user.valid?
  expect(user.errors.count).to eq 2
  expect(user.errors[:first_name]).to include "is too short (minimum is 2 characters)"
  expect(user.errors[:last_name]).to include "is too short (minimum is 2 characters)"
end
```

The `user.valid?` call will run the new user against the validations which will populate the errors.

That's a very verbose test to do a unit test - I highly recommend [shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers).  You can test the above in just two lines:

```
it { is_expected.to ensure_length_of(:first_name).is_at_least(2) }
it { is_expected.to ensure_length_of(:last_name).is_at_least(2) }
```

Comment: Ended up getting this error; `expected: 2 got: 8 (compared using ==)`

Comment: well I don't think the `errors.count` bit is a good item to test.  Clearly you have 6 other validations that aren't passing with the above.  Most would advise you to get rid of that expectation.

Comment: Would you recommend just creating separate tests for these attributes then? I'm all for creating DRY code but if it gets more complex than necessary than I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down voted but this isn't the best way to do unit tests.  I'll edit my answer to show the alternative I use.

Comment: added info regarding shoulda_matchers.  Take a look at this as good way to DRY up your tests.